# Do I have to make sure my record only match with one row when using JOIN with DELETE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
DELETE A
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON
   A.ID=B.ID
WHERE B.Status='OK'
```

The records from these join might resulted in more than one rows, for example:

Table A

```
ID
1
2
```

Table B

```
ID   Status
1    OK
1    OK
2    OK
```

Do I have to make sure my record only match with one row? Because in these example, ID `1` will have 2 rows.

Apologize for bad english.

Comment: A `DELETE` will delete any matched rows. If you have many matched rows, you'll delete many rows. If this doesn't answer your question, I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Since you delete records from table A, If you don't have any other record with the same id in the same table, you can be sure you will delete only one record.

Comment: FYI, I don't think using a `LEFT JOIN` is a good idea here. It's basically made irrelevant by the `WHERE` clause, but it's not a good practice - without the `WHERE` clause, you'll delete all the rows in your table `A`. Use an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you **don't** have to ensure a 1 row result per row to delete. The engine will delete all rows **from the deleting table** that matches your joining or where conditions, even if they are being selected for more than 1 row.

The important part is which table are your deleting, make sure not to delete the wrong one!